# How do I pass parameters (e.g. -o CDNW) from Buildr to ScalaTest?

Tags: buildr, scalatest

Currently I'm only able to say:

```
test.using(:scalatest)
```

Buildr documentation says that class Buildr::Scala::ScalaTest supports the following options:

- :properties - Hash of system properties available to the test case.
- :environment - Hash of environment variables available to the test case.
- :java_args - Arguments passed as is to the JVM.

But those are parameters to *test cases* and *JVM* only, not to ScalaTest ?

```
D:\>buildr --version
C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.4-x86-mswin32/lib/buildr/java/packaging.rb:62: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
Buildr 1.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

See my discussion on Twitter with Alex: http://twitter.com/#!/boia01/status/27605157764145153

If you still need this, please open an issue in Buildr's bug tracker, and we'll address it :)